# How to perform operations on memory map without loading whole file into memory?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

An approximately 4.3 GB memory map I want to take the log of without loading the whole thing into memory. Is there a way to assign `cl` that minimizes amount of memory used?

```
import numpy
import psutil

print(psutil.virtual_memory().available)  #32156053504
cc = numpy.memmap(r'data//cc.dat',mode='r',dtype=float)
print(psutil.virtual_memory().available)  #32156049408  #very little memory used
cl = numpy.log(cc) + 1
print(psutil.virtual_memory().available)  #23610658816  #8.6 GB used
```

I want to take slices of `cc` and `cl` which normally wouldn't require loading all of cc.dat into memory.

Comment: One of the big advantages of memory mapping a file is that you don't have to care about managing the actual memory used by your process. The operating system will utilize available RAM or swap out what's required to keep your system running. If you want to micro manage don't memory map.

Comment: `numpy.log(cc) + 1` **always** creates a new array in memory, regardless of what `cc` is (actually, 2 arrays)

Comment: Yeah I noticed in the memory usage. Is there a way to vectorize the call or make it a function to minimize the memory usage?

Comment: I eventually just want to take slices of the array, which normally wouldn't require loading all of cc.dat into memory

Comment: it *is* vectorized.

Comment: Anyway, you sohuld try using the `out` paramter to `numpy.log`, then don't use `+` (which will **always create a new array object**) and use `np.add` instead, again, using the `out` paramter. So something like `np.add(np.log(cc, out=cc), 1, out=cc)`. Does that improve the memory usage?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
 I get ValueError: output array is read-only with numpy.log(cc, out=cc)

Comment: This is because you load the input file in read mode with `mode='r'`... If data cannot be stored in RAM, it needs to be stored somewhere, so it should be on the disk. Thus, you should either use an in-place computation (read-write mode) or use another memory map so tell to Numpy where to put the result. Note that using `np.add`+`np.log` with `out` parameter is fundamentally inefficient : it performs 2 walks of the array (2 reads + 2 writes). The only way to avoid that in Numpy is to do the operation *chunk by chunk*. Alternatively, you can use Cython/Numba to avoid that.

Comment: By the way, if you use an SSD, note that out-of-core operation like this tends to significantly reduce the remaining lifespan of the SSD, especially for larger input like >10 GiB and when the SSD has TLC/QLC cells. You need a SLC SSD for such computation (or only use the SLC cache if you have any). SLC cells are significantly more expensive than TLC/QLC. HDD does not have this problem but they are much much slower for such a task (eg. 5~50 times slower).